# Installing pgcrypto Extension

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have this password hash function that hashes a password to sha256. I've already got it running in pgadmin3 in a local database. I've done it by importing the extension, a feature that has been added a few versions ago.

To my schoolwork I need to run the trigger in a phppgadmin server but when I execute

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

I get

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/pgcrypto.control": No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this without having to change my hash to a weaker one (md5 or sha1)?

Comment: Please don't use a single pass of a hash function to hash passwords, and please don't roll your own.  See [my answer to Password Verification - How to securely check if entered password is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22572839/1967612) and the canonical [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/39623).  If you get a good PostgreSQL PBKDF2/BCrypt/SCrypt implementation, I'd like to add it to [my github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords), where I have several password hashing algorithm examples, currently very crude.  Try OpenSSL or PolarSSL.

Comment: `pgAdmin` and `phpPgAdmin` are both just GUIs accessing (the same) Postgres database. Also, there are a couple of similar questions: http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=postgres+contrib

Comment: I've voted to close this because it's a packaging problem, without knowing what distro he's using we can't answer how you install pgcrypto.

Answer (score 13):

I'm assuming that you want to create this extension in another server. I'm guessing that the server didn't get the "postgresql contrib" package installed. This package contains the "standard" extensions that are available from the PostgreSQL source code.

I think you need to get the system administrator to install the required package for your OS.

For Debian and Ubuntu it's the "[postgresql-contrib-9.1](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pgcrypto.control&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any)" package, for other platforms it has a similar name.

Comment: You need to do `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.1` or it depends on the version of your postgres.

Comment: For Alpine Linux, `apk add postgresql-contrib`.